# Google Charts bar/column chart getColumnRange() unexpected value from DataView

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, googlevis

I'm trying to get the min and max value of a Dataview with the help of getColumnRange(). Unfortunately the values I get are not the ones I'd expect. Can someone advise me how I can get the correct values? The value I'd expect as max is 331M (the highest bar on the bar chart), but I get 8,5M. I tried to better my understanding of the DataView object with console.log(), however that didn't quite help me (line 65-71)

https://jsfiddle.net/zhp5rny6/3/

```
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
cols: [
{id:"","label":"Products","pattern":"","type":"string"},
{id:"","label":"Manila","pattern":"","type":"number"},
{id:"","label":"Bangkok","pattern":"","type":"number"},
{id:"","label":"New York","pattern":"","type":"number"},
{id:"","label":"Sydney","pattern":"","type":"number"}],

rows:[
{c:[{v:"Glasses"},{v:-1270.7287},{v:-4486.0961},{v:-1019.4662},{v:3763827.8335}]},
{c:[{v:"Joysticks"},{v:145543.985},{v:2108039.5802},{v:266392.5277},{v:6006566.18690001}]},
{c:[{v:"Laptops"},{v:1723781.2686},{v:4435404.56789999},{v:7060065.3164},{v:17514581.1763}]},
{c:[{v:"PS4"},{v:78002243.0557997},{v:47591320.6768999},{v:43832560.9528002},{v:161580254.021496}]},
{c:[{v:"XBOX One"},{v:10507117.0145001},{v:8059953.41120002},{v:14103816.4604002},{v:34676509.4036004}]},
{c:[{v:"Smartphones"},{v:2373067.7893},{v:-53954.2187},{v:30783391.8722},{v:37288122.5537999}]},
{c:[{v:"Chairs"},{v:86583.2876},{v:71082.0195},{v:79813.2918},{v:22959813.0499999}]},
{c:[{v:"CPU"},{v:12479599.4709999},{v:22650137.9890997},{v:17562381.7794999},{v:25589299.8099997}]},
{c:[{v:"RAM"},{v:null},{v:-59.1},{v:282.7517},{v:1461239.6186}]},
{c:[{v:"Table"},{v:-566.5377},{v:-217.3444},{v:-865.114},{v:356870.886599999}]},
{c:[{v:"Water"},{v:870883.521900001},{v:1128581.9856},{v:1177332.008},{v:3922057.50240001}]}]
});

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: 'short'
  });

    for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    formatter.format(data, i);
    }

    var view = getDataView(data);

  function getDataView(dataTable) {
    var dataView;
    var viewColumns = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
      addViewColumn(i);
    }

    function addViewColumn(index) {
        viewColumns.push(index);
        if(index == (dataTable.getNumberOfColumns() - 1)) {
            viewColumns.push({
            calc: function (dt, row) {
                for(var e = 0; e < dt.getNumberOfRows(); e++) {
                    var value = 0;
                    for(var u = 1; u < dt.getNumberOfColumns(); u++) {
                        value += dt.getValue(row, u);
                    }
                    return formatter.formatValue(value).toString();
                }
                },
            type: 'string',
            role: 'annotation',
            });
        }
    }

    dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
    dataView.setColumns(viewColumns);
    for(var z = 0; z < dataView.getNumberOfColumns(); z++) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(dataView.getColumnRange(z)));
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(dataView.getViewColumns()));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(viewColumns));
    return dataView;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason you get `"8.5M"` instead of `"331M"` is because the column type = `'string'`

alphabetically, `"8.5M"` is greater than `"331M"`

to correct this issue, use a column type of `'number'`.
when building the data view annotation column,
and return an object with both the value (`v:`) and formatted value (`f:`).

```
  viewColumns.push({
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      for(var e = 0; e < dt.getNumberOfRows(); e++) {
        var value = 0;
        for(var u = 1; u < dt.getNumberOfColumns(); u++) {
          value += dt.getValue(row, u);
        }
        return {  // <-- return object here
          v: value,
          f: formatter.formatValue(value)
        };
      }
      },
    type: 'number',  // <-- change to number
    role: 'annotation',
  });
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load("44", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
cols: [
{id:"","label":"Products","pattern":"","type":"string"},
{id:"","label":"Manila","pattern":"","type":"number"},
{id:"","label":"Bangkok","pattern":"","type":"number"},
{id:"","label":"New York","pattern":"","type":"number"},
{id:"","label":"Sydney","pattern":"","type":"number"}],

rows:[
{c:[{v:"Glasses"},{v:-1270.7287},{v:-4486.0961},{v:-1019.4662},{v:3763827.8335}]},
{c:[{v:"Joysticks"},{v:145543.985},{v:2108039.5802},{v:266392.5277},{v:6006566.18690001}]},
{c:[{v:"Laptops"},{v:1723781.2686},{v:4435404.56789999},{v:7060065.3164},{v:17514581.1763}]},
{c:[{v:"PS4"},{v:78002243.0557997},{v:47591320.6768999},{v:43832560.9528002},{v:161580254.021496}]},
{c:[{v:"XBOX One"},{v:10507117.0145001},{v:8059953.41120002},{v:14103816.4604002},{v:34676509.4036004}]},
{c:[{v:"Smartphones"},{v:2373067.7893},{v:-53954.2187},{v:30783391.8722},{v:37288122.5537999}]},
{c:[{v:"Chairs"},{v:86583.2876},{v:71082.0195},{v:79813.2918},{v:22959813.0499999}]},
{c:[{v:"CPU"},{v:12479599.4709999},{v:22650137.9890997},{v:17562381.7794999},{v:25589299.8099997}]},
{c:[{v:"RAM"},{v:null},{v:-59.1},{v:282.7517},{v:1461239.6186}]},
{c:[{v:"Table"},{v:-566.5377},{v:-217.3444},{v:-865.114},{v:356870.886599999}]},
{c:[{v:"Water"},{v:870883.521900001},{v:1128581.9856},{v:1177332.008},{v:3922057.50240001}]}]
});

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: 'short'
  });

  for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
  formatter.format(data, i);
  }

  var view = getDataView(data);

  function getDataView(dataTable) {
    var dataView;
    var viewColumns = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
      addViewColumn(i);
    }

    function addViewColumn(index) {
    viewColumns.push(index);
    if(index == (dataTable.getNumberOfColumns() - 1)) {
      viewColumns.push({
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          for(var e = 0; e < dt.getNumberOfRows(); e++) {
            var value = 0;
            for(var u = 1; u < dt.getNumberOfColumns(); u++) {
              value += dt.getValue(row, u);
            }
            return {
              v: value,
              f: formatter.formatValue(value)
            };
          }
          },
        type: 'number',
        role: 'annotation',
      });
    }
    }

    dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
    dataView.setColumns(viewColumns);
    for(var z = 0; z < dataView.getNumberOfColumns(); z++) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(dataView.getColumnRange(z)));
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(dataView.getViewColumns()));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(viewColumns));

    return dataView;
  }

  var options = {

    annotations: {
    alwaysOutside: true,
    textStyle: {
      fontSize: 10
    }
  },
    height: 400,
    isStacked: true
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="columnchart_values"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a very big help!